# Gitlab pipeline job read not existing docker-compose.yml commands

Tags: docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

here is  .gitlab.yml

```
stages:          # List of stages for jobs, and their order of execution
  - test
  - deploy
  - cleanup

variables:
  GIT_STRATEGY: clone

unit-test-job:   # This job runs in the test stage.
  stage: test    # It only starts when the job in the build stage completes successfully.
  script:
    - echo "Running unit tests... This will take about 60 seconds."
    - docker compose -f Docker/test/docker-compose.yml down
    - docker compose -f Docker/test/docker-compose.yml build backend
    - echo "Finish"


deploy-job:      # This job runs in the deploy stage.
  stage: deploy  # It only runs when *both* jobs in the test stage complete successfully.
  environment: production
  script:
    - echo "Deploying application..."
    - echo "Application successfully deployed."


cleanup_job:
  stage: cleanup
  script:
    - echo "Cleaning up"
    - rm -rf "%CACHE_PATH%/%CI_PIPELINE_ID%"
  when: always
```

this is docker-compose.yml in Docker/test

```
version: '3.8'


services:
  backend:
    container_name: test_backend2
    build:
      context: ../../backend_fastapi
    env_file:
      - $env
    depends_on:
      - db
    command: >
      bash -c "sleep 10 && pytest tests"


  db:
    container_name: test_postgres
    image: postgres:15.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data:z
    env_file:
      - $env
```

previously it was other volumes

```
  - ./db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  - ./sql/create_tables.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_tables.sql
  - ./sql/fill_tables.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/fill_tables.sql
```

but right now, all the time  i got error of gitlab job with such logs

```
Running with gitlab-runner 16.4.0 (6e766faf)
  on git-Legion-T5-26IRB8 fzGTdsjHD, system ID: s_543b064700c6
Preparing the "shell" executor 00:00
Using Shell (bash) executor...
Preparing environment 00:00
Running on git-Legion-T5-26IRB8...
Getting source from Git repository 00:00
chmod: changing permissions of '/home/gitlab-runner/builds/fzGTdsjHD/0/portal/backend/Docker/test/sql': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of '/home/gitlab-runner/builds/fzGTdsjHD/0/portal/backend/Docker/test/sql/fill_tables.sql': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of '/home/gitlab-runner/builds/fzGTdsjHD/0/portal/backend/Docker/test/sql/create_tables.sql': Operation not permitted
chmod: changing permissions of '/home/gitlab-runner/builds/fzGTdsjHD/0/portal/backend/Docker/test/db_data': Operation not permitted
chmod: cannot read directory '/home/gitlab-runner/builds/fzGTdsjHD/0/portal/backend/Docker/test/db_data': Permission denied
```

I already don't have such instruction with *.sql files, why it made deleted instruction (volumes) and how to fix it?

Comment: It doesn't look like it's even trying to run the docker commands yet... It seems like it's failing to checkout the repository. Probably an issue with the permissions of the user account configured in the executor -- and/or maybe you've accidentally set the directories/files to be owned by root.

Comment: chown of gitlab-runner helps just for one execution, after the case repeat